# Pytest failed to collect tests

Tags: python, pytest

Pytest ceases to collect tests, it happens spontaneously one test passed and another run just shows that no test ran.

```
├── __init__.py
├── pytestdebug.log
├── readme.md
├── requirements.txt
├── setup.py
├── task
│   ├── cli.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __pycache__
│   └── task_cm.py
├── test
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __pycache__
│   └── task_cm_task.py
```

```
└─$ python3 -m pytest
=================================================================================
test session starts 
==================================================================================
platform linux -- Python 3.9.1+, pytest-6.2.2, py-1.10.0, pluggy-0.13.1
rootdir: /home/mbienias/skygate
collected 0 items                                                                                                                                                                      

================================================================================ 
no tests ran in 0.01s 
=================================================================================
```

```
└─$ python3 -m pytest --collect-only
================================================================================= 
test session starts 
==================================================================================
platform linux -- Python 3.9.1+, pytest-6.2.2, py-1.10.0, pluggy-0.13.1
rootdir: /home/mbienias/skygate
collected 0 items                                                                                                                                                                      

============================================================================= 
no tests collected in 0.01s
=============================================================================
```

However, it can see defined fixture

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
fixtures defined from test_task_cm
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
setup_database
    test/test_task_cm.py:8: no docstring available
```

Edit: Link to debug.log [Pastebin.com](https://pastebin.com/8gmsgesC)

Comment: `--collect-only --debug` and have a look at pytestdebug.log afterwards.

Comment: do your test names start with a `test_` prefix?

Comment: @eemz I have added link to pastebin with log file, I do not see anything that could lead me to the solution.

Comment: what's your exact folder structure and where are you running pytest from within that structure?

Comment: @gold_cy yes, tried also with `_test.py` suffix

Comment: no, your actual function test names, not the file

Comment: @gold_cy You are winner, without noticing I have changed function name, so it didn't had `test_` prefix. Please create Answer I will mark it as resolution. Thank you.

Comment: no need, this is a common problem and I think cluttering up solved answers with another duplicate answer is fruitless, glad it is working for you again